# Disabling ActiveX a specific ocx (or specific ActiveX controls) in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject

In IE users can disable the ActiveX scripting. But this disables all the ActiveX controls on the browser.

Is it possible to only make one *.ocx file not to work in IE?

-Datte

Answer (score 0):

Use Killbit per ActiveX Control.
But this makes the control not to load in KillBit aware applications like MSWord, MSExcel.